# How to navigate back with form input?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

In my `view1` I have a post form, with the action to a post route.

The post function in the controller saves the request's data to a session and redirects to `view2`.

In that view I want to have a link to navigate back to `view1` but with the form filled out.
For validation purposes, I already have `old()` in place.

I expected the follow to work, but the function does not exists on the route helper:

```php
&larr; <a href="{{ route('view1')->withInput() }}">Back</a>
```

Here is the controller:

```php
public function view1()
    {
        return view('view1');
    }

    public function post_create(CreateRequest $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('data', $request->all());

        return redirect()->route('view2');
    }

    public function view2()
    {
        return view('view2', [
            'data' => session('data'),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I understand the scenario but did not get your point I mean what the problem is ?

Comment: When I navigate back, there is no form input anymore

Comment: If you have stored that data in session so why are you not retrieving data from session
Like this session('key') ? session('key') : old('key') ? old('key') : '' it will check if session has data so it get data from session and check in elseif part old field has data or not and else do nothing

Comment: That's it - thanks! If you would add this as an answer, I can rate it. Otherwise I'd delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have stored that data in session so why are you not retrieving data from session.

Like this

> session("key") ? session("key") : old("key") ? old("key") : ""

Or

> ```
> if(session("key")) {
>     return session("key");
> } elseif (old("key")) {
>     return old("key");
> } else {
>     return "";
> }
> ```

It will check if session has data so it get data from session and check in elseif part old field has data or not and else do nothing